# issue with CSS border

Tags: html, css, border

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="top">
<div id="first">
</div>
<div id="second">
</div>
<div id="third">
</div>
</div>
​
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
#first{
    position: absolute;
    left:100px;
    top:100px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
#second{
    position: absolute;
    left:200px;
    top:100px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:green;
}
#third{
    position: absolute;
    left:100px;
    top:200px;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}

#first:hover{
    border-color:"000";
    border-width:5px;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

​Also please have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hrishikeshp19/Q5zt2/2/) fiddle.

I dont understand why border is not applied to first div.

Comment: for the record: `border: #000 5px solid;`

Comment: Also, everything appears to be working. What do you expect the result to be when you hover over the red box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the way the box model works in css...if you reduce the box on hover as seen in [this updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5zt2/9/), it will work how I believe you expected it to.

Answer (score 3):

your `border` is working but hide behind other `div's` where you `hover` over it.
You can use `box-sizing` property for this.

Write like this:

```
#first{
    position: absolute;
    left:100px;
    top:100px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Q5zt2/6/

Comment: +1 for `box-sizing`.  Might help to include a link explaining what it's all about and why it's happening (eg: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Answer (score 1):

Try writing your #first:hover CSS as:

```
#first:hover{
    border-color:#000;
    border-width:5px;
    border-style:solid;
    height:90px;
    width:90px;
}
```

Your border is showing but without adjusting the height and width for the added thickness of the border it looks like it isn't applying it properly.

See your [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5zt2/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index:1 property in first:hover it will work

Comment: And it will change the size of the first div.  Probably not desired.

Answer (score -1):

The border is applied on hover as that is what you have said in the CSS

```
#first:hover{
   border-color:"000";
   border-width:5px;
   border-style:solid;
}
```

Change it to this if you want the border to appear always...

```
#first{
   border-color:"000";
   border-width:5px;
   border-style:solid;
}
```